# Formatar valor inteiro no formato "000"

Tags: c#

Em *vb6* utilizava a seguinte linha de código que permitia formatar o valor "1" para "001"

```
Format$(Nivel, "000")
```

Em *C#* estou a utilizar a seguinte com nomenclatura parecida.

```
string.Format("000", 1);
```

No entanto o valor retornar é sempre "000"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para funcionar, segue 2 exemplos (um com [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) e a outra com [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"{i}".PadLeft(3,'0'));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000}", i));
```

<sub>[Exemplo ONLINE Ideone](https://ideone.com/sxglUB)</sub>

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Método String.PadLeft (Int32, Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Você também pode usar o formato direto na _string interpolada_ (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings), que na verdade é como se fosse um atalho para o `String.Format()`, dessa forma: `$"{i:000}"`

Answer (score 6):

É possível desse jeito também.

```
int a  =  3;
string valor = a.ToString("D3");
```

Comment: Eu não entendi o -1 !!!

Comment: O "D3" acrescenta também os 3 dígitos.

Comment: Correto, eu também não entendi o problema, por isso da minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

A forma correta de fazer o que você quer é usando o [**`PadLeft()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string valor = "1";
valor.PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Comment: não seria `valor.PadLeft(3,'0');` ?

Comment: ops, isso mesmo :P vou corrigir a resposta. Vlw, @LeandroAngelo